# Magento1.9 : How to set value of deafult store when other store is select

Tags: magento-1.9, system-configuration

my problem is currently I'm in English store and want to set counter to default
store counter but every time English store counter is updated.

[image]

below image is deafult store.

[image]

update counter value using following query:

```
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig(self::ORDER_COUNTER,$counter,'stores',$order->getData('store_id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code,

```
$storeId =Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeCode, 'code')->getId();    
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig(self::ORDER_COUNTER,$counter,'stores',$storeId);
```